# CSS not with nested selectors

Tags: css

i am wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

```
td:not(#brackets_div > table > tbody > tr > td) { background-color:#FF0000; }
```

unfortunatly it doesn't seem to work,
tried it multiple ways. And i can't find a good explenation

Comment: It seems likely due to the restriction of the [`:not()` (negation pseudo-class)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation) being allowed only [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS3, `:not` [only accepts a simple selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#negation). The `>` combinators prevent it from being a [simple selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#selector-syntax)--the CSS4 specification refers to that instead as a [complex selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#complex).